# slideToggle and toggleClass working together?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, toggleclass

You can see my current code here http://jsfiddle.net/Km3vf/6/.

I want to click on the button, have the class applied to the div, delay, then open the panel. On a second click, it should remove the class and slide the panel back up.

When I click on the button again, it removes the class (perfect) but does not toggle the slide. Can anyone help me please?

```
<html>
<div class="third">

    <h2 class="toggle">CLICK</h2>

    <div id="panel">
        <p>Panel details go here.</p>
    </div>

</div>
</html>

<style>
.third {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
.full {
    width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
#panel {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    padding:2%;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    clear:both;
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $(".third").toggleClass("full").queue(function(){
    $('#panel').slideToggle(1000).delay(1000);
});
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the queue does the trick, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Km3vf/7/

I've also changed the delay in the chain so now it's:

```
$('#panel').delay(1000).slideToggle(1000);
```

See if that's what you wanted.

If you want it to first slideUp when closing, I'm afraid you won't be able to do it using one toggle function, but will have to check for the current state make slight modifications.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Km3vf/8/

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you! If I had two sets of this on a page but only wanted one open at a time (opening one, closes the other) how would I do that?

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, you'd need to check which one is clicked, and open that one and close the other. Maybe the toggle functions make it confusing, here is the version with slideUp/Down instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Km3vf/9/ Make sure you have no duplicate IDs (like panel)

Comment: Great, thank you. Can I really push my luck and ask if you can do a jsfiddle with the two sets please?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Km3vf/13/ Because of the delays, they might go crazy when you click them rapidly, so I suggest you add a variable denoting the currently opened one, and use that for checks rather than checking for the `full` class. But you get the general idea.

Comment: @Shomz thats nice, should be apart of your answer

Comment: @r3wt Thank you, though it's not the best code (far from it), it's like one quickfix on top of another. The whole thing should probably be rewritten, having separate close/open functions to avoid all the siblings/children/parent mess. I wouldn't like anyone to use this as a starting point... and we've drifted a lot from the original question anyway. :)

Comment: @Shomz agreed. i like to use jquery cookie for things like this.